# Ionic fire event on input text value changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In Ionic, how can you catch an event on a text input field when its value changes?

The input field:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-text-change="searchMenu()">
```

The controller:

```
// ...
    $scope.searchMenu = function () {
        alert('changed')
        console.log(1);
    };
// ...
```

Nothing happens when typing into the text field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ionic is Angular in a nutshell, and angular has two general ways of watching for changes:

1. Use [`$scope.$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch):

markup:

```
 <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search" />
```

and code:

```
  $scope.$watch('search',function (oldValue, newValue) {
     alert('changed')
     console.log(1)
  });
```

For the sake of completeness there are also [`$watchGroup`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup) and [`$watchCollection`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection)

2. Using `ng-change` directive togher with `ng-model`:

markup:

```
 <input type="search" placeholder="Search" 
        ng-model="search" 
        ng-change="onSearchChange()" />
```

and code:

```
 $scope.onSearchChange = function () {
    alert('changed')
    console.log(1)
}
```

There are also advanced ways of getting changes, like creating directive that is talking to ngModel directive controller and/or creating custom formatter and parser to work with ng-model.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add an `ng-model` attribute and use `ng-change` instead of `ng-text-change`.

`ng-change` is a built-in angular directive which fires events when the binded model (`ng-model`) changes. [ngChange documenation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

So your html would be like:

```
<input ng-model="inputValue" ng-change="searchMenu" type="search" placeholder="Search">
```

In your controller, you need to add a $scope variable like:

`$scope.inputValue = ''`

Answer (score 3):

It's **ng-change** not *ng-text-change* and you must have **ng-model** on that input element to trigger ng-change event

[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)